# Jetty8 FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration

Tags: jetty

When I want to start my Jetty8 Server on Windows XP I get an Error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in start.con
fig or command line.
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

I start my Jetty Server like this:
java -jar path/to/jetty/start.jar

I read that I have to specify my Jetty Home somewhere, is this the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself, you have to start the jetty server with

```
shell> start java -jar start.jar
```

to load all environment variables correctly.